# How do I push to a git server on a container?

Tags: git, docker

On my host machine, I'm able to create a second user: `admin` and `push` to that user's git folder using:

`admin@localhost:folder`

When I create a Docker container hosting a git server, after exposing `port 22` how do I `git push` from my local machine to `localhost:22` which would be the location of the container's ports?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054339/how-to-deploy-code-from-localhost-to-docker-containers-using-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are trying to bind docker container port 22 to already occupied port 22 of your host. You need to map container ssh server to other not occupied port of your host e.g. 5000.

You can expose particular ports during container start-up with flag "-p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT":

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5000:22 docker_image
```

Then you should be able to reach container's GIT server:

```
git add container container_user@127.0.0.1:5000/folder
git push container branch_name
```