# git remote add origin docker container

Tags: git, docker

I have to setup a docker container with git and cml.yaml file inside. So I have the container and I did run with -p 3000:3000, I started with
git remote add origin IP_adress_container:/myFile

and when I did from my local machine git push origin master I get an error:

```
ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository 

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So, how I can to fix that? how I can use git push from my local machine to my container. How to set up the command line:
git remote add origin "container"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I push to a git server on a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784487/how-do-i-push-to-a-git-server-on-a-container)

Comment: thanks but i get the same issue.

Comment: Than share your Dockerfile and how you have setup the `sshd`

Comment: sorry i didn't setup the ssh, the Dockerfile is a simple ubuntu